# zend framework gmail

Tags: zend-framework, email, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to use zend mail for sending in one of my application.

I'm not sure what is the basic requirement for using zend_mail.

```
$this->transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp(
        'smtp.gmail.com', 
        array(
            'ssl'=> 'tls',
            'port'=> '587',
            'auth'=> 'login', 
            'username'=> 'email@email.com', 
            'password'=> 'password'
    ));

Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($this->transport);
```

and while sending mail

```
$mail->send($this->transport);
```

and handled error using

```
$e->getCode().$e->getMessage();
```

script gives me error 05.5.2

I'm not able to understand what is the issue.

Comment: i tried with 'ssl' and port '465' as well same error

Answer (score 2):

The port should be 465!!!!
Then it works. By me as well!

Comment: did you try the port name without quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

Leave the port off:

```
$config = array('auth'=>'login', 'username'=>'', 'password'=>'', 'ssl'=>'tls');
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
$mail->send($transport);
```

Comment: Can you post your full mail code? Is this on localhost or live? You may be missing a php extension

Comment: which php extension i have to use ? it is on live server. infact we have 2 different servers and it is not working on both the servers

Comment: openssl, but for two live servers not to have that would be surprising